# Creating a drop shadow with guassian blur

Tags: graphics, shadows, inkscape

How can I add a drop shadow to a `\includegraphics` picture? The effect should be very minute just to be a little bit eye pleasing. I know you can use `\shadowbox` in `fancybox` package but the output would not be like this.

Sample:

[image]

Created with the drop shadow effect in `Inkscape`.

Comment: This might help: [Faded drop-shadow using `tikz`-based rounded rectangle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11272/5764)..

Comment: Here's a link to another drop-shadow question (that led to a package on CTAN): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50422/86

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`Caramdir's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3954) to [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11272/3954)) (all credit goes to **Caramdir**).

Using the `\drawshadow` command form the linked answer, I defined a `\shadowpicture` command with one optional argument (the options that will be passed to the optional argument of `\includegraphics`), and a mandatory argument (the name of the file containing the image). Using `\colorlet` one can change the values for `innercolor` and `outercolor`, controlling the values used for the shadow.

Using the `xparse` package one can easily define `\shadowpicture` to have three optional arguments (the two colors and the optional values for `\includegraphics`) and a mandatory one (the name of the image file).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

% code adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3954

% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}

\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!05}

% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}


\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\shadowimage[width=5cm]{image}\par\bigskip

\shadowimage[width=8cm]{image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A little improvement: now the shadow size adjusts automatically depending proportionally on the image size:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

% code adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3954

% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}

\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!05}

% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mylen

\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
\setlength\mylen{\wd0}
\ifnum\mylen<\ht0
\setlength\mylen{\ht0}
\fi
\divide \mylen by 120
\def\shadowshift{\mylen,-\mylen}
\def\shadowradius{\the\dimexpr\mylen+\mylen+\mylen\relax}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\shadowimage[width=6cm]{image}\par\bigskip

\noindent\shadowimage[width=.9\linewidth]{image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that these are fungi that are responsible for the blurring effect and not the LaTeX code. :-)

Comment: Whatever you do with this image looks fantastic.

Comment: Perfect! The macro `\shadowimage` is wonderful. I wished I could vote up +10 :)

Comment: Could you do one more improvement? Suppose the total size of the image should not change at all. So `\includegraphics` image should be downscaled abit. What is the total width which is added by shadow? radius + shift?

Comment: @rowman I think I don't understand your comment; you want to change the width of the shadow but I don't understand in which way. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: The shadow is added to the image so the total width and height of the image is increased by the shadow width and height. Thus, the image dimension is increased in total. I want to have the image with the shadow at the same size as of the the original image. Therefore the original image should be downscaled a bit, the shadow is applied and it becomes again the same size. Thanks !

Comment: This is perfect. Is it possible to modify the script to add shadow around a tikz figure rather than an actual image? I mean kind of framing your tikz figure, and place them in a white rectangle with drop shadow?

Answer (score 4):

Cool effect! But images with the same color as the background can be difficult to see in the upper left corner.

I added a dark frame because it looks better when using white images on white background.

```
\shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=innercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius/12,\shadowradius/12)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowradius/12,-\shadowradius/12)$);%Frame
```

So, the complete preamble code (without the proportionally on the image size) would be:

```
\usepackage{tikz} % Use image shadows
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}
\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!05}
% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=innercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius/12,\shadowradius/12)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowradius/12,-\shadowradius/12)$);%Frame
    \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}
% Define image shadow command
\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

And this is the result without shadow, and below including framed shadow:
[image: Example without shadow and with framed shadow]

To have more rounded corners it's possible to add the command "rounded corners", but the result will not be perfect and some artifacts will probably appear in the shadow.

```
\usepackage{tikz} % Use image shadows
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}
\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!05}
% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
    \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
    \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=innercolor,rounded corners] ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius/12,\shadowradius/12)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowradius/12,-\shadowradius/12)$);%Frame
    \filldraw[rounded corners] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}
% Define image shadow command
\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\node[rounded corners,draw=black,anchor=south west,inner sep=1] (border) at (image.south west) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

[image: Example using rounded corners]

Comment: What can I do to have rounded black border on the image? I tried "rounded corners", but those corners are covered by the image and cannot be seen.

Comment: See new code in post for "rounded corners".

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone comes back to this, I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/latex-photo-with-rounded-corners/688642#688642) stack exchange thread combined with Alain Matthes's answer to create a `.tex` file that you can include into your own LaTEX project (with `\include{yourFileNameHere.tex}`. You can then call `\shadowImage[]{image}` like you would `\includegraphics[]{image}` and it will create an image with rounded corners and a centered drop shadow. An example is shown below:

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

% code adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11483/3954

% some parameters for customization
\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}

\colorlet{innercolor}{black!10}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!0}

% this draws a shadow under a rectangle node
\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        % \shade[outercolor,right color=black!40,left color=black!40] ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius/12,\shadowradius/12)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowradius/12,-\shadowradius/12)$);%Frame
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mylen

\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
\setlength\mylen{\wd0}
\ifnum\mylen<\ht0
\setlength\mylen{\ht0}
\fi
\divide \mylen by 50
\def\shadowshift{0,0}
\def\shadowradius{\the\dimexpr\mylen+\mylen+\mylen\relax}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip [rounded corners=\shadowradius * 0.8] (0,0) rectangle coordinate (centerpoint) (\the\wd0, \the\ht0);
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\end{scope}
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```